# grails - testing delete()

Tags: unit-testing, grails

I just wonder why one method to test delete() works as expected, but another does not?
In the following test case:

```
    def cFound = new Client( ... ).save()

    def cFoundId = cFound.id
    cFound.delete()
    assertEquals 0, Client.count()
```

... assertEquals 0, Client.count() passes, but ...

```
    assertFalse Client.exists( cFound.id )
    assertNull Client.get(cFoundId)
```

... both fail. What could be the underlying reason?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unit or integration test? You should test persistence with integration tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to flush the context, in order to clean the caches:

```
cFound.delete(flush: true)
```

Comment: will need to remember that one.